# CSS background-image doesn't display

Tags: css, hover, anchor

I am confused about using CSS to display an image using the an empty `<a>` element.

```
<a class="header" href="#"></a>
```

does create the clickable area as specified in the following css:

```
.header { width: 50px; height 50px; background-image:url('images/picture.png') }
```

however, will not display the picture.  If I also include:

```
.header:hover { background-image:url('images/picture.png'); }
```

then it will display the picture.  My aim is to use the CSS to employ [this method](http://kyleschaeffer.com/user-experience/pure-css-image-hover/) of image-to-image replacement, but I don't have the basics understood yet it would seem.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle with your code.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up realizing I made a typo.  Upon fixing it, the image does appear properly.  Do you mean that it is not good practice to do as such?

Comment: Can it be, by any chance, that the missing semicolon has something to do with this problem?

Comment: Are there any missing semicolons?

Answer (score 0):

Your on the right track with your css. You must add display:block to allow the anchor tag to pick up the hight.

```
.header { width: 50px;
          height 50px; 
          background:url('images/picture.png'); 
          display:block;
}
```